# how to replace special characters in a string by "_"

Tags: flutter

hello i have a string ch and i want to replace the special characters if it exist by "_"
how can detect all special characters is there another way .
can we use replaceAll and include all the special characters

```
  for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
  var char = s[i];
  if (char = "/" || char ="." || char ="$")
  {
      s[i] ="_"
  } 
}
```

Comment: how about using `.replaceAll()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this with regex

```
_string.replaceAll(RegExp('[^A-Za-z0-9]'), '_');
```

This will replace all characters except alphabets and numbers with _

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to use RegEx inside a .replaceAll() method.
In your case you can use a regex that matches all character other than English Alphabets..

```
String result = s.replaceAll(RegExp('[^A-Za-z]'), '_');
```

Or you can be more specific and create a regex of your requirement

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this solution to replace some classes of special characters:

Gist of it:

```dart
const textWithSpecialCharacters =
    "!\"#\$%&'()*+,-./0 9:;<=>?@A Z[\\]^_`az{|}~σςΣßǲǱǳﬀſK₨�ⅷⅧµΜⓗ◌ͅΙǇǈǉᄈ￡h◌ͪhh＾｀⁓⁻₋−‐−–—⸗➖™";

final regExp = RegExp(
  r'\p{Punctuation}',
);

final result = textWithSpecialCharacters.replaceAll(
  regExp,
  "_",
);
```

Full solution:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  test('characters to sort with priority', () async {
    const allSortsOfCharacters =
        "!\"#\$%&'()*+,-./0 9:;<=>?@A Z[\\]^_`az{|}~σςΣßǲǱǳﬀſK₨�ⅷⅧµΜⓗ◌ͅΙǇǈǉᄈ￡h◌ͪhh＾｀⁓⁻₋−‐−–—⸗➖™";
    expect(
      [
        r'\p{Punctuation}',
        r'\p{Separator}',
        r'\p{General_Category=Currency_Symbol}',
        r'\p{General_Category=Math_Symbol}',
        r'\p{General_Category=Modifier_Symbol}',
      ]
          .map(
            (
              mSource,
            ) =>
                RegExp(
              mSource,
              unicode: true,
            ),
          )
          .fold(
            allSortsOfCharacters,
            (
              previousValue,
              element,
            ) =>
                previousValue.replaceAll(
              element,
              "_",
            ),
          ),
      "_______________0_9_______A_Z______az____σςΣßǲǱǳﬀſK_�ⅷⅧµΜⓗ◌ͅΙǇǈǉᄈ_h◌ͪhh___________➖™",
    );
  });
}
```

Resources that I used to reach this conclusion:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions/Character_classes

https://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#General_Category_Property

https://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Extender

https://richardjharris.github.io/all-sorts-of-things-you-can-get-wrong-in-unicode-and-why/